# issue with link on video in iOS when power is low

Tags: ios, html, autoplay

When playing an inline, autoplay video on an iPhone with a low battery, iOS requires the user to tap on the video to start it. (this makes sense... They want to save battery life by preventing videos from playin)

However, from what I can tell, this also leads to an adverse side effect: It is not possible to click through if the video has an href link.

Any workarounds to this?

Here's an idea of how I'm trying to do it:

```
<a href="http://www.link.com">
<video width="100%" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
<source src="https://source.mp4" preload type="video/mp4"></video>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

add   &rel=0 like this

```
src="https://source.mp4&rel=0"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added&rel=0 to the end, but that seems to just break the code entirely. Some initial googling suggests that this is code used for YouTube hosted videos (I'm not expert though!). In my case the videos are just hosted on Amazon S3. In case there are other suggestions, or I'm doing this wrong I'd love the input.